# how can boost signal be triggered when it is used in a driver/wrapper of a device

Tags: driver, point-cloud-library, openni

As an example from boost signal doc_view [sample](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/signals/example/doc_view.cpp), I can see that the signal is triggered (and by then, the callback is evoked) by calling the "()" operator of the signal.

```
class Document
{
public:
    typedef boost::signal<void (bool)>  signal_t;
    typedef boost::signals::connection  connection_t;

public:
    Document()
    {}

    connection_t connect(signal_t::slot_function_type subscriber)
    {
        return m_sig.connect(subscriber);
    }

    void disconnect(connection_t subscriber)
    {
        subscriber.disconnect();
    }

    void append(const char* s)
    {
        m_text += s;
        m_sig(true);   // <- here triggers the signal
    }
```

This pattern cannot be seen when I read pcl openni wrapper codes in module pcl io openni_camera at [link](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/io)

The registration of signals is written in function Grabber::registerCallback in grabber.h ([link](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/include/pcl/io/grabber.h)) to create an array of signals of this class signals_ array. However, there isn't any place in this repository that signals_i is invoked in some sort. The registration:

```
Signal* signal = dynamic_cast<Signal*> (signals_[typeid (T).name ()]);
boost::signals2::connection ret = signal->connect (callback);   // <- here registration

connections_[typeid (T).name ()].push_back (ret);
shared_connections_[typeid (T).name ()].push_back (boost::signals2::shared_connection_block (connections_[typeid (T).name ()].back (), false));
```

I really can't get how these signals are triggered in such a driver/wrapper.

Could someone clear me out?

Thank you

Comment: I am wondering is it too specific? improper? or out of scope that I haven't got a single reply in several days?